# Safe way to construct a vector inside a loop and return it outside that scope?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

I have a code sample, and I'd like to ask you to review this and tell me if my understanding is correct. I am learning C++, and so I apologize if these questions are rudimentary. I have read about how C++ handles memory management, but I haven't found practical examples. I am trying to write some myself.

**Code Sample:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> containerOfVectors;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    std::vector<int32_t> innerVector;
    innerVector.push_back(1);
    containerOfVectors.push_back(move(innerVector));
    innerVector.push_back(2);
    innerVector.push_back(3);
    innerVector.push_back(4);
    std::cout << "innerVector " << std::to_string(i) << " contains: " << std::endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < innerVector.size(); k++) {
        std::cout << "\t" << std::to_string(innerVector[k]) << std::endl;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    std::vector<int32_t> vector = containerOfVectors[i];
    std::cout << "Vector " << std::to_string(i) << " contains " << std::to_string(vector.size()) << " element(s)" << std::endl;
}
----------
Output:
----------
innerVector 0 contains: 
    2
    3
    4
innerVector 1 contains: 
    2
    3
    4
Vector 0 contains 1 element(s)
Vector 1 contains 1 element(s)
```

I have a (container) vector of vectors, and I am looping and creating two vectors inside the loop, which are added to the `containerOfVectors`. I add one element to the vector inside the loop, move it to the `containerOfVectors`, and then add three additional elements.

In the second loop, when I iterate `containerOfVectors` and print out the values, I only see `1`. The values `2`, `3`, and `4` are not there.

My understanding of this is that the `move` call is copying the elements of `innerVector` into a new vector, and at that point `innerVector` becomes empty. And hence, at the end of the loop iteration, `innerVector` will only contain 2, 3, and 4 since only 1 was moved over. And then `innerVector` is destroyed.

Is that move actually a "copy", or does it "move" the same "2"? And would it (or how would it) differ if the value was a struct instead of an integer? And how can I test that myself? By printing the memory address, or can the memory address be different for the same underlying instance?

I apologize there's a lot to unpack here. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot access variables out of scope?!? What do you mean, why do you need to instantiate the variable only inside the loop? Elaborate please.

Comment: The `move()` leaves innervector valid (empty) thus your results. If you examine the elements in the container vector of vectors they will be "1" Nothing unexpected. move moves the guts or rather, it causes the guts to be moved. It copies nothing.

Comment: At the end of the body of your first loop, innervector is destroyed and then recreated when the loop runs again. Hence your pushback of 2, 3, 4 are pointless. If you declated innervector outside of the body of the loop yoiu'd get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move semantics creates new objects. It is not a copy or assignment, it is a move-constructor that is invoked. Thus, if you call `move(innerVector)` you actually create a new vector object as entry in containerOfVectors. This automatically contains the content/data of the original `innerVector` at the moment you make the call. Afterwards, the innerVector is empty, and whatever you do with it will not affect the new object inside containerOfVectors. There is no link between those two distinct objects. The memory address of an object created with move-construction is certainly always different from its original object.

This fully explains the output of your example. With any other data type inside the vector, also structs, this will be just the same.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for this great explanation. When you say it “automatically contains the content/data of original innverVector”, does it copy that content/data or just move it from the old vector to the new vector?

Comment: Move constructors are there to improve the performance of resource allocation. Thus, in a well written library -- which stl certainly is -- the data is not copied but the internal memory (of the data) is directly used. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector in particular also comments 8+9.